# Animating geometry node setup along curve

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am trying to animate a shape (let's say a plane) with some geometry nodes alongside a curve. My current setup includes a plane with the following modifiers: the Geometry nodes, an array (fit curve and merge checked) and a curve modifier.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LuyFamY5s-VjuSh21OaWjjt8ugGfMOCB/view?usp=sharing).

Any ideas on how I can animate the process of extending the curve? I could only find [this answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0pyRKMLyOs) online, but it doesn't work with any mesh.

[Here's a crude example of what I mean](https://youtu.be/dY6yAPg_uOc). I want to be able to animate the extrusion, movement and/or rotation of the curve while the geometry nodes are automatically updating the result.

Comment: honestly, i have no idea what you want to have? Could you maybe add a video or a sketch how it should work/look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use as geometry input a curve.

Then you can paint the curve like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]